# How to access a docker insecure registry from docker 17.10 ee preview 3 installed on windows server 2019?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, windows-server-2019

I just installed Docker for windows 2019 and I'm unable to find how to connect to a private insecure registry.

I created the file daemon.json in the docker installation folder but that didn't helped.

Comment: What is your error after `docker login` ?

Comment: I cannot login because even trying to login it tries to connect using https. "http: server gave http response to https client"

Comment: Please post the content of your `daemon.json` file.

Comment: { "insecure-registries": ["<IP>:<PORT>"] }

Comment: I just noticed that I need to install the windows insider preview version for docker to work, maybe both issues are related

Comment: nonono!! you just need to configure this `insecure-registries`. I already connected windows 10 docker client with a Nexus (docker registry) with http

Comment: Windows server 2019 and windows 10 are not the same. And Docker Desktop is not the same as Docker Enterprise.